# Tomcat 8 enable gzip compression in a java application configuration xml file

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, tomcat8

Is it possible to enable gzip compression in a java application configuration xml file? I cannot (I have no permission) modify server.xml file and alter  element.

Is this possible in application's configuration XML file?
Will override work? 
Is there another way? e.g. programmatically?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Filter` to intercept the `HttpServletResponse` and compress it ? for instance : http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/filters.html

Comment: Your best bet is to request that your administrators enable compression for you. You can Filters and stuff like that to the application, but it's really better done at the `<Connector>` level for a number of reasons.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an option.